# A cookie in the shape of a foot

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositional-phrases

1. A cookie in the shape of a foot.
2. A cookie in the shape of foot.

Is foot without an article OK? If so, what does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your examples

> A cookie in the shape of a foot.

is grammatically correct

[image: here]

> A cookie in the shape of foot.

is grammatically incorrect, however

> A cookie in the shape of feet.

is grammatically correct and could mean a single cookie which looks like more than one foot

[image: here]


or multiple feet made from a single *type* of cookie *(dough)*

> *Fookies* can be made from a traditional sugar cookie recipe.

[image: here]

Comment: I'm impressed -- it would never have occurred to me to look for illustrations!

Comment: I'm more than impressed; I'm flabbergasted. How on Earth did @Peter find a photograph of a cookie die in the shape of **two feet!** Apparently he has such things just lying around in case they are needed someday. Mirabile dictu!

Answer (score 2):

No, 2. doesn't seem correct. It sounds strange. I think this is because this "foot" is unspecified. So we need an article to signal that it is [unspecified](https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/articles/4/indefinite-articles-a-and-an/). By using the article *a*, it implies that the cookie has the general shape of a foot--any foot, a typical foot.

> a cookie in the shape of **a** foot.